# Spawn a program from Perl and communicate with it via STDIN/STDOUT

Tags: perl, fork, stdin

I have a C program that simply runs a loop that reads a JSON structure from STDIN and writes a line to STDOUT.

In order to support a variety of front-end formats, I want to write a Perl program that repeatedly reads data, converts it to JSON, submits it to the C program, and receives the output -- as if I were using `qx//` to invoke the C program, only without launching it afresh each time.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39693924/522385) describes the same problem, except the parent process is in C. I wondered whether Perl provided a way to do this more easily. It would be preferable (but not essential) for the C program to stay the same and be unaware whether it was forked by Perl or run from the command line, if possible.

To illustrate (note - using Perl for the child, but hopefully the same principles apply):

File `parent.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
$|++;

# {{ spawn child.pl }}
while (1) {
    print "Enter text to send to the child: ";
    my $text = <>;
    last if !defined $text;
    # {{ send $text on some file descriptor to child.pl }}
    # {{ receive $reply on some file descriptor from child.pl }}
}
```

File `child.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
$|++;
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line .= ", back atcha.\n";
    print $line;
}
```

Execution:

```
$ parent.pl
Enter text to send to the child: hello
hello, back atcha.
Enter text to send to the child:
```

**UPDATE:**

The caveats for using `open2`, stated both by @ikegami below and in [Programming Perl / Interprocess Communication](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch16_03.htm), don't seem to me to apply here, given:

- I don't care about STDERR (which would require `open3` and `select`)
- I control the child source code and can therefore guarantee that autoflushing occurs.
- The protocol is strictly send one line, receive one line.

Comment: How do you demote the end of a request? How do you denote the end of a response? Is the child's output truly unbuffered?

Comment: Both the request and the response are one "line" of text terminated by `\n`. And doesn't `$|++` guarantee that the child's newline-terminated line will get flushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given these conditions from the original question ...

- You don't care about reading STDERR
- You control the child source code and can therefore guarantee that autoflushing occurs.
- The protocol is strictly send one line, receive one line.

... the following will work. (Note that the child is written here in Perl but could also be C.)

**parent.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Open2;
$|=1;
my $pid = open2(my $ifh, my $ofh, 'child.pl') or die;
while (1) {
    print STDOUT "Enter text to send to the child: ";
    my $message = <STDIN>;
    last if !defined $message;
    print $ofh $message;   # comes with \n
    my $reply = <$ifh>;
    print STDOUT $reply;
}
close $ifh or die;
close $ofh or die;
waitpid $pid, 0;
```

**child.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
$|=1;

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    print STDOUT $line . ", back atcha.\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Just make sure not to send another request before receiving the response of the previous one.